# ajax code define error or doesn't respond

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am new to ajax. Studies basic from wrook's blog.
I used the below code to insert into my db using ajax.
But the code does't print any thing other than 'Just wait a second'.

the JsFiddle  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/abelkbil/VwFa8/) 

Ajax code is as below:-

```
/* ---------------------------- */
/* XMLHTTPRequest Enable */
/* ---------------------------- */

function createObject() {
var request_type;
var browser = navigator.appName;
if (browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
    request_type = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
else {
    request_type = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
return request_type;
}

var http = createObject();

function insertReply() {
if (http.readyState == 4) {
    var response = http.responseText;
    // else if login is ok show a message: "Site added+ site URL".
    document.getElementById('insert_response').innerHTML = 'User added:' + response;
}
}

/* -------------------------- */
/* INSERT */
/* -------------------------- */
/* Required: var nocache is a random number to add to request. This value solve an Internet          Explorer cache issue */
var nocache = 0;

 function insert() {
// Optional: Show a waiting message in the layer with ID login_response
document.getElementById('insert_response').innerHTML = "Just a second...";
// Required: verify that all fileds is not empty. Use encodeURI() to solve some issues about   character encoding.

var username = encodeURI(document.getElementById('Username').value);
var name = encodeURI(document.getElementById('Name').value);
var password = encodeURI(document.getElementById('Password').value);
document.getElementById('insert_response').innerHTML = 'h ' + username + ' ' + name;
// Set te random number to add to URL request
nocache = Math.random();

// Pass the login variables like URL variable
http.open('get', 'insert.php?name=' + name + '&username=' + username + '&password=' + password);
http.onreadystatechange = insertReply;
http.send(null);
}​
```

The php code to insert db is ::--

```
  if(isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['username'])&& isset($_GET['password'])){

 $name= $_GET['name'];
 $username= $_GET['username'];
  $password= $_GET['password'];
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `vidyasims`.`user_accounts` (`UserID`, `UserName`, `Name`, `Password`)   VALUES (NULL, '. $username. ','. $name. ', '. $password. ');";
 $insertSite= mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

  //If is set URL variables and insert is ok, show the site name -->
 echo $username;
} else { 
 echo 'Error! Please fill all fileds!';
```

support is welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Note- The above code doent add a new user to db!

Comment: This is tagged jquery, yet I don't see any jquery.

Comment: Please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: @copy is there any problem with SQL code! or is it bad to use SQL through ajax

Comment: Note that IE11 does not return "Microsoft Internet Explorer" for appName, instead it returns NetScape http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533079(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Also, did you copy paste the code in the fiddle? because, there is a discrepancy in the "Username" in javascript and html

Answer (score 1):

You are missing ids for your html form inputs, and cannot use document.getElementById() to retrieve their values a quick fix:

```
<td><input type="text" id="Name" name='Name' value='' ><br></td>
                 <td><input type="text" id="Username" name='UserName' value=''></td>
                 <td><input type="password" id="Password" name='Password'></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

why you are not using jQuery Ajax like this, I think it is the very simple and easy way to your work:

**JQuery Code**

```
 <script language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myHtmlButtonID").bind("click",function(){
       $('#insert_response').html("Just a second...");
       var username = $('#Username').val();
       var name = $('#Name').val();
       var password = $('#Password').val();
       /* add some validation if needed here */
       $.ajax({
                 url: "yourPHPpage.php",
                 data: {
                       name: name,
                       username:username,
                       password: password
                       },
                type: "get",
                success: function(txt){
                      $('#insert_response').html('User added:' + response);
                      },
                error: function(xhr){
                      $('#insert_response').html('Error: - '+xhr.status+ ' '+ xhr.statusText);  
                      }
               });
     });
});
</script>
```